# how to print a label from my PHP web app to an Epson usb receipt printer

Tags: php, printing

I just need someone to show me how to print a label from my PHP web app to an Epson USB receipt printer.
it should not be an asp page. It has to be written in PHP. Second, the page must be served from a remote server, not localhost. I'm waiting to visit such page on your server to print the label/receipt to my local POS printer.

Comment: So what exactly is your question? How to print from a web page, how to do it with php instead of another language on the server, how to format the data for your Epson printer, ...?

Comment: Please specify the exact details of the printer you want to use. Is it [this one](https://www.epson.co.uk/products/sd/pos-printer/epson-tm-t20ii-series)?